# After installing keras and tensorflow, python script crashes with Segmentation Fault (core dumped)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04

[image] Why does import statement (eventually leading to keras import) work only after handling a deliberate exception???????

I have a python3.5 project with multiple main.py entry points.

One entry point runs on server, another on client(s) using pycos to communicate (network IPC).

My server/main.py used to execute fine, but after installing keras and tensorflow with

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --user
```

the server/main.py crashes reading

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have monitored RAM on the server VM, hard disk space and nothing indicates why server/main.py is crashing... <strike>It doesn't even import keras OR tensorflow in the import trace.</strike> I guess _ *init* _.py import trace eventually leads to the module which imports keras / tensorflow packages

Can anyone advise on how to find the issue?

**requirements.txt**

```
jsonpickle
matplotlib
seaborn
numpy
pycos
jsonpickle
statsmodels
pandas
sklearn
pymongo
keras
tensorflow==2.0.0-beta1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out pycos executes an underlying scheduler which somehow interferes with Tensorflow (causing seg faults) if the python modules which call pycos are exposed in the _ _ init _ _.py of their respective python sub-packages.

Removing monitoringSimulation/monitor.py etc.. imports from monitoringSimulation/ _ _ init _ _.py fixes the issue.

Will submit a bug to pycos as I will eventually need to expose monitor.py module to other subpackages.